# Writing a new function: configMotor(speed, direction)

Tags: motor

How can I create a function that can control a DC motor's speed and direction?

```cpp
configMotor(int speed, direction){
   pwmVal = speed;

   //need help with code for picking direction
}

//move FORWARD
void moveForward(){
  analogWrite(pwn, pwmVal);
  delay(sDelay);
  digitalWrite(ina, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(inb, LOW);
}

//move BACKWARD
void moveBackward(){
  analogWrite(pwn, pwmVal);
  delay(sDelay);
  digitalWrite(ina, LOW);
  digitalWrite(inb, HIGH);
}
```

I don't know what to write in the code for `configMotor` function so that it can choose going forward or backward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is pass a parameter to config that says forward or backwards (was direction).
This parameter then sets the values of that the pins INA/B will be set to, because they are opposite.

Does that make sense?  If not add a comment with you question and I'll try and clarify.

```
int inaDirection = LOW;
int inbDirection = LOW;

void configMotor( int speed, bool forwards = true)
{
   pwmVal = speed;
   inaDirection = forwards?HIGH:LOW;   // ? and : are the same as an if statement, just more compact.
   inbDirection = forwards?LOW:HIGH;
}

// move no need for forward and reverse anymore
void move()
{
    analogWrite(pwn, pwmVal);
    delay(sDelay);
    digitalWrite(ina, inaDirection);
    digitalWrite(inb, inbDirection);
}
```

Comment: why is bool forwards set to equal to true in the parameter declaration?

Comment: `bool forwards = true` means by default the function should go forwards.  You can call `configMotor(40); or `configMotor(40, true);` they both mean the same thing, where as `configMotor(40, false);` means go backwards.  I added the default value to make it clearer to you that true meant forwards, I guess it didn't work :)